# Как сделать вывод денег из мобильного приложения?

Tags: android, google-play, мобильные-приложения, монетизация

Доброго времени суток! Краткая суть приложения :

1. В приложении пользователь может донатить через `in app purchase` за
   определенные услуги
2. Другой пользователь может выполнять задания и зарабатывать игровую
   валюту или смотреть рекламу, а потом, обменивая игровую валюту,
   выводить реальные деньги. Вывод средств должен осуществляться на
   электронный кошелек ( Webmoney и другие)

Мобильное приложение не относится к категории игры, азартные игры и тд .

Можно ли сделать вывод напрямую из кошелька разработчика в `Google Play` в автоматическом режиме? Нужны ли какие-то документы чтоб вообще предоставить услугу вывода? И впустят ли приложение в `store`  где есть `in apps purchase` и вывод средств ?

Comment: Думаю, с выводом средств _произвольным пользователям_ будет много юридических, налоговых и бюрократических вопросов, причём независимо от направленности приложения. Например, это можно чисто теоретически назвать "доходом физического лица".

Comment: Человек заработал валюту, хочет вывести и делает запрос, при этом пойнты списывают, вы говорите что это занимает n дней. Он формирует форму вывода в любом подходящем для вас виде, потом уже как эти деньги вы будете переводить ему это другой вопрос, хоть ручками на карту бросайте. Дальнейших решений огромное множество, ну естественно все можно автоматизировать.

Comment: Вы говорите про бюрократию и вообще проблемы с ,,документами,, У меня возник вопрос - эти проблемы могут возникнуть с Google или с государством в котором я живу ? Google не все равно ? Вроде для Google главное чтобы их правила не нарушали, я просто видел приложение с подобной схемой (ввод и вывод средств) Спасибо за ответ ! @yeputons

Comment: @АртурКрячко я думаю, что Google может быть не всё равно хотя бы на формальном уровне, если вы как-то через них будете выводить деньги. Или если приложение в Google Play - тут вообще надо правила магазина читать, наверняка там есть что-нибудь вроде "не нарушать местное законодательство", а Google лишние потенциальные проблемы ни к чему.

Comment: @yeputons  А если выводить деньги деньги с in-app себе на карточку с помощью swift перевода  ( не из кошелька разработчика в Google Play) а потом оттуда оплачивать вывод самих пользователей в приложении ? Вообще Google может пустить в store приложение где есть ввод и вывод средств выше перечисленным образом, где оплата вывода это уже мои проблемы, и к Google это никак не относиться ? Спасибо за ответ!